# git difftool $BASE and $LOCAL are reversed

Tags: git, diff, local, radix

I merged a feature branch into master with `--no-commit`. When doing a `git diff` I see the correct changes: some lines have been added in the feature branch. When using `git difftool` I get a reversed result. The tool shows that the new lines were already present and are not there any more.

I checked git config and in fact $BASE refers to the changes and $LOCAL refers to the original version.

```
[difftool "p4merge"]
path = C:\\Program Files\\Perforce\\p4merge.exe
cmd = p4merge.exe $BASE $BASE
```

This shows actually all the new changes in the working dir on both sides.

```
[difftool "p4merge"]
path = C:\\Program Files\\Perforce\\p4merge.exe
cmd = p4merge.exe $LOCAL $LOCAL
```

This shows the original version on both sides.

```
[difftool "p4merge"]
path = C:\\Program Files\\Perforce\\p4merge.exe
cmd = p4merge.exe $BASE $LOCAL
```

This shows the result I was expectiong but it's the wrong order?

Eclipse shows the expected result not the one from the difftool.
I also tried different tools: kdiff3 and p4merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool):

> When **git difftool** is invoked with this tool (either through the `-t`
>    or `--tool` option or the `diff.tool` configuration variable) the
>    configured command line will be invoked with the following
>    variables available: `$LOCAL` is set to the name of the temporary
>    file containing the contents of the diff pre-image and `$REMOTE` is
>    set to the name of the temporary file containing the contents of
>    the diff post-image.  `$MERGED` is the name of the file which is
>    being compared.  `$BASE` is provided for compatibility with custom
>    merge tool commands and has the same value as `$MERGED`.

To unpack that a bit:

- `git difftool` needs, first, the hash IDs of two commits (or something else suitable; see below).  Let's call these the "left" and "right" sides of the diff.  When you use:

  ```
  git diff commit1 commi2
  ```

  or

  ```
  git difftool commit1 commit2
  ```

  the idea is to obtain instructions that would tell you how to change what's in `commit1` into what's in `commit2`: how to change each file in the left side into each file in the right side.
- The stuff inside a commit—the frozen files in the snapshot—is in a form that any program that *isn't* Git cannot use.  So Git is going to *extract* the files from those commits into some temporary area.  These files may have wild temporary names like `/tmp/a9ZF3xq` or some such.
- `$LOCAL` has the wild / unpredictable temporary name of the left-side file.
- `$REMOTE` has the wild / unpredictable temporary name of the right-side file.
- `$MERGED` has the actual file name, such as `src/sub/somefunc.py` or whatever.  If this file exists on disk, its contents may not be those of *either* the left *or* the right side file!  `$MERGED` should be used only to show the *name* of the file, not to access any contents.
- `$BASE` really should not be used, but if do you have something that uses it, it's just going to be identical to `$MERGED`.

So, reading the *contents* of a file named `$BASE` or `$MERGED` is incorrect and will result in the wrong instructions sometimes.  Do not use either one—use `$LOCAL` and `$REMOTE` instead, with `$LOCAL` holding the left-side contents and `$REMOTE` holding the right-side contents.

#### Some `git diff` / `git difftool` commands use the work-tree

I said above that `git difftool`—which is mostly the same as `git diff`—needs the hash IDs of two *commits*, but that's not quite true.  What it really needs is two *trees* to compare.

Every commit has a tree, in Git, because every commit contains a complete snapshot of all files as of their state at the time you (or whoever) *made* the commit.  But there are two more trees you can use:

- The *index* or *staging area* contains your proposed next commit.  That is, it has a copy of every (to-be-committed) file.  If you run `git commit` right now, the new commit will snapshot the files that are in the index / staging-area.
- Your *work-tree* is a tree of files that you can, using `git add`, use to overwrite the files in your index / staging-area.

Both `git diff` and `git difftool` can use the index and/or the work-tree as left and/or right side.  If you use the index as one of the two sides, its files are in the same Git-only format as the ones in commits, so these files must be copied to temporary files that could have wild temporary names.  But if and when you use the *work-tree* as one of the two sides, well, its files are all ordinary everyday files.  Git can, and will, just direct the merge tool to look right at those files.

That means that *when you use the work-tree as one of the sides* (and **only** in this case), `$LOCAL` or `$REMOTE` will have the name of a work-tree file in it, and that work-tree file has the contents that your tool is supposed to examine.  In this case, `$BASE` and `$MERGED` will have the *same name*.  This case is *very common* because, as with `git diff`:

```
git difftool
```

with *no* arguments means "compare the index contents to the work-tree contents".  With *one* argument:

```
git difftool HEAD
```

Git compares the given commit to the work-tree.  That is, in both of these cases, the right-side "commit" is whatever is in the work-tree.  So here, `$LOCAL` is a temporary file name with what's in the `HEAD` commit or the index, but `$REMOTE`, `$BASE`, and `$MERGE` are all just the name of the work-tree file!

Hence, of course:

```
<command-to-view> $LOCAL
```

will show you what's in the left side, because that's what `$LOCAL` *is:* a temporary file containing what's in the left side.  Meanwhile:

```
<command-to-view> $BASE
```

will show you what's in the right side, because `$BASE` matches `$REMOTE` and `$REMOTE` is the name of a file containing what's in the right side.  Using:

```
<command-to-view/compare-both-of> $LOCAL $BASE
```

will work *for this case*, but not in general.  You must use:

```
<command-to-view/compare-both-of> $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

and if that command has the ability to say "this is a comparison of the contents that were stored in a file named ____" (fill in the blank), you can fill in the blank using `$BASE`.